# Hierarchical linear regression analyses, but with logarithms?

Tags: regression, anova, t-test, matlab, multilevel-analysis

I was ask to do a linear regression analyses of my variables. I have Reaction times. Can you recommend me a linear regression analysis (hierarchical?) and tell me whether I should transform my raw data into logarithms before that analysis?

My reaction times are in milliseconds.

Comment: Welcome to the site. With just the information you have given, it isn't possible to give good advice. I wrote [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) on my blog. It may help you improve the question.

Comment: I second the advice of @PeterFlom. You could also take a look at my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77196/anova-with-huge-dataset-use-only-the-mean-for-each-condition/80288#80288) as a starting point to analyzing reaction time data.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, log transformation is performed on Y to make its distribution look more like Gaussian. If your Y already has a nearly gaussian distribution, the transformation is not necessary.
For the 'hierarchical' part, you need to distinct between different levels (see the classic students within schools example, or Goldstein good and free book: http://www.arnoldpublishers.com/support/goldstein.htm.)